# How to have a Bulma dropdown be full width and centered

Tags: css, bulma

I want to have a bulma dropdown be as wide as the viewport and centered, no matter where the trigger is.  Example is below...any ideas on how this can be accomplished?  Take the snippet to full page to see the issue.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container level">
  <div class="dropdown is-hoverable level-item">
    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
      <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu4">
      <span>Menu 1</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu4" role="menu">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
          <p>I want this dropdown centered in the viewport</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown is-hoverable level-item">
    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
      <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu3">
      <span>Menu 2</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu3" role="menu">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
          <p>This one should be centered as well</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Centered vertically or horizontally?

Comment: centered horizontally

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/2ooz9ypf/

Comment: Yes, except that it won't scroll with the rest of the page.

Comment: Or, to clarify, the vertical position should stay relative to the trigger (or the top of the page, which is all I need in this instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adjusting the `left` and `right` position of both `dropdown-menu`.

I've used `nth-of-type` in the example below, you could instead add a class to each `dropdown` to make it more readable.

You will need a media query to reset the values, example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  .dropdown.is-hoverable .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/2ooz9ypf/2/)

```css
.dropdown.is-hoverable .dropdown-menu {
  width: 100vw;
}

.dropdown:nth-of-type(1).is-hoverable .dropdown-menu {
  left: initial;
  right: -50vw;
}

.dropdown:nth-of-type(2).is-hoverable .dropdown-menu {
  left: -50vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  .dropdown.is-hoverable .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container level">
  <div class="dropdown is-hoverable level-item">
    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
      <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu4">
        <span>Menu 1</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu4" role="menu">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
          <p>I want this dropdown centered in the viewport</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown is-hoverable level-item">
    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
      <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu3">
        <span>Menu 2</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu3" role="menu">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
          <p>This one should be centered as well</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi consequuntur, est expedita velit labore atque dolores voluptatum eius voluptatem excepturi eum pariatur. Officia pariatur, quae expedita consectetur voluptatibus vitae a.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting..I wasn't aware of the initial keyword...this does fix my example, though I'd prefer something where I don't have to know in advance the relative horizontal positions of the triggers...but I'll play with this for a bit, and if nothing else comes in, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Each `.dropdown` takes up 50% of the container in your layout. So using 50vw is doable... If you want to change their position or add additional buttons, you'll either need to recalculate, use `position: fixed` or possibly use a javascript solution... best of luck anyway